# Can I have an <input> and <label> with different parent elements?

Tags: css, html

For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle" />

<nav>
    Nav stuff
</nav>

<main>
   <label for="nav-toggle">Menu</label>
</main>
```

For use in an a css only menu panel like this: http://codepen.io/jimahyland/pen/mAVGmj

It seems to work fine, but is there anything fundamentally wrong with this approach?

Comment: No, that's fine and normal.

Comment: Yes, you can have it.  Nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `input` and `label` can have different parents.

Most standard block-level elements, such as `body`, `div`, `article`, `section` and `aside`, accept [***flow content***](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1), which includes [`input`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element) and [`label`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element).

As long as the parent accepts flow content or [***phrasing content***](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1), `input` and `label` can exist as a child element.